# Difference between XYZ rotation and Theta_Phi_Psi rotation

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, calibration

What is the difference btw  XYZ rotation  and Theta,Phi,Psi rotation.

```
Theta [deg] ; -0.66057811029304
Phi [deg] ; 20.6061074480986
Psi [deg] ; -0.471074371882115
```

Theta phi psi the vector of rotation between to cameras how can i convert it to a xyz rotation in python

Comment: what's your attempt at solving this?

Comment: I have some data from a challenge, i have the transformation btw and object and camera1 and then i have the transformation btw camera2 and object and finally i have the transformation btw camera 1 & camera 2. The problem is in the data the rotation btw cam1- object & cam2-object is a xyz rotation and the rotation btw cam1-cam is a theta phi psi rotation !

Comment: have you tried using google and solving this question on your own? Something like this: https://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/3d-rotations-and-euler-angles-in-python/